# QUERY - Google Sheets - filter with conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to filter some rows of this sheet

[Google sheet sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar7Fc.png)

I'm using the following query:

=query(Jira_query!$A:$I;"SELECT A WHERE E contains '&SDP&' AND C IN ('To Do','In Progress')")

But I'm only getting this error:
Error
PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "C "" at line 1, column 39. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...

I would appreciate some help here, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the ampersands before and after `SDP`. That is a string literal and should just be sitting between the single quotes.

In addition, I don't think `QUERY` supports `IN`; instead, use `MATCHES` with a pipe-separated list.

Finally, you only need to reference `A:E` in the `QUERY`, since you don't reference any columns beyond `E` in the `SELECT` clause.

So try this:

`=QUERY(Jira_query!$A:$E;"SELECT A WHERE E CONTAINS 'SDP' AND C MATCHES 'To Do|In Progress'")`